# Confusion in construction of B+ tree?

Tags: database, b-tree

while inserting a new key value in b+ tree ,if we find that given key is exactly same to key to which it is compared ,then which way we move to insert it ,right or left? 
        In different words ,while traversing a b+ tree ,if BP is block pointer

```
BP-->x //Block pointer points to x 
K1|BP|K2 //what will be properties of x's value ,k1<x<=k2 or k1<=x<k2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always insert at the end of a set of duplicates in a B-tree.

Comment: so that would be right hand side,because we insert from left to right,OK?---oh no no..my bad ..got that.thanks